# How to get IP or Hostname of connected Windows RDP users?

Tags: session, wmi, rdp, wsh

I have a vbs script that monitors users that are remotely logged in to a server
It uses "qwinsta" to get the usernames and I can simply loop through waiting for a disconnect.

But qwinsta doesn't return hostname or ip address of the remote user. I've searched all morning and can't find any cmd command or wmi command to get the ip/host of a connected user based on their username or session id.

Does anyone have any other ideas to get this info? I found this external utility that gives the ip address: http://home.fnal.gov/~jklemenc/tslistusers.html but I'd rather not use an external program. I assume that it is using some wmi or other method to get the ipaddress that I could do within my own script somehow.

I know I can use netstat and filter port 3389 to get only the RDP sessions and get the IP's that way, but I have no way to know which IP belongs to which user from that point.

Answer (score 1):

This information is exposed through the (mostly) undocumented API WinStationQueryInformationW. It is not exposed through WMI or any command line utility or COM object, as far as I know.

If you can use a .NET language, you could use the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) to handle the Win32 API calls -- see ITerminalServicesSession.RemoteEndPoint (download the latest trunk build [here](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project51) by logging in as a guest). It should be possible to use Cassia from VBScript [using tlbexp and regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx), but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the code below in a batch file to pass a text file of hostnames into an array and query each for rdp session info...
(just make sure the Server_List.txt file is beside the batch file you create)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo RDPSessionINFO > ./results.txt
echo ============== >> ./results.txt

set i=0
for /F %%a in (Server_List.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set array[!i!]=%%a
)
set n=%i%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !array[%%i]! >> ./results.txt && qwinsta /server:!array[%%i]!>> ./results.txt && echo =================== >> ./results.txt

start notepad.exe ./results.txt
```